# Placing page indicators on top of a data table jQuery

Tags: jquery, datatables

My .coffee file for the table looks like this:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#example').dataTable({
    "bPaginate": true,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": true,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bAutoWidth": false
  })
```

The corresponding table looks like this

[image]

I know the command to place the search box underneath the table but i don't know how to place the page indicator on top of the table. Any ideas?

Comment: This question doesn't pertain to RoR, and is more related to jQuery Datatables. Please update the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to mingle with the [**`dom`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option. The default value is `lfrtip`, set `p` (for `p`agination) at the beginning instead of the very end :

```js
jQuery ->
  $('#example').dataTable({
    "sDom": 'plfrti', //preserving hungary notation for clarification
    "bPaginate": true,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": true,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bAutoWidth": false
  }
```

You need to correct `.dataTables_paginate` default `float: none` as well :

```css
.dataTables_paginate {
  float: left !important;
  clear: none;
}
```